# Using SFINAE to select the interface to implement

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfinae

I'm trying to select which interface a concrete class implements based on a template parameter. In the simplified example below there are two interfaces with methods of different names - the `Implementation` class needs to provide the method implementations, depending on the template parameter.

If I use `IntType` - it should implement `IntInterface` (`getInt()` and `setInt(int)`).
If I use `DoubleType` - it should implement `DoubleInterface` (`getDouble()` and `setDouble(double)`).

In order to achieve this, I created a traits class which determines which interface should be used (`InterfaceType`), but also has another parameter to be used for SFINAE.

The idea is that if I use e.g. `MyTypeTrait<Type>::MyTypeInt` but the relevant trait class has no `MyTypeInt` definition, the compiler will throw this possible overload (for e.g. `setInt()`), and will use another one. That's where the dummys should kick in - they have different arguments and they're not virtual.

However, it doesn't work. See below the compiler errors.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (VC12).

```
struct IntInterface
{
    virtual int getInt() const = 0;
    virtual void setInt(int value) = 0;
};

struct DoubleInterface
{
    virtual double getDouble() const = 0;
    virtual void setDouble(double value) = 0;
};

const int IntType = 0;
const int DoubleType = 1;

template <int Type>
struct MyTypeTrait;

template <>
struct MyTypeTrait<IntType>
{
    using MyTypeInt = int;
    using InterfaceType = IntInterface;
};

template <>
struct MyTypeTrait<DoubleType>
{
    using MyTypeDouble = double;
    using InterfaceType = DoubleInterface;
};

template <int Type>
struct Implementation : public MyTypeTrait<Type>::InterfaceType
{
    // Actual interface implementation for the case of IntType
    virtual typename MyTypeTrait<Type>::MyTypeInt getInt() const override { return 0; }
    virtual void setInt(typename MyTypeTrait<Type>::MyTypeInt value) override {}

    // Dummys for SFINAE - to be used in the case of DoubleType
    typename int getInt(int) const { return 0; }
    void setInt() {}

    // Actual interface implementation for the case of DoubleType
    virtual typename MyTypeTrait<Type>::MyTypeDouble getDouble() const override { return 0.0; }
    virtual void setDouble(typename MyTypeTrait<Type>::MyTypeDouble value) override {}

    // Dummys for SFINAE - to be used in the case of IntType
    typename double getDouble(int) const { return 0.0; }
    void setDouble() {}
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Implementation<IntType> myInt;
    Implementation<DoubleType> myDouble;
}
```

**Compiler errors:**

```
1>c++-tests.cpp(50): error C2039: 'MyTypeDouble' : is not a member of 'MyTypeTrait<0>'
1>          c++-tests.cpp(26) : see declaration of 'MyTypeTrait<0>'
1>          c++-tests.cpp(61) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Implementation<0>' being compiled
1>c++-tests.cpp(50): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getDouble'
1>c++-tests.cpp(50): error C2433: 'Implementation<0>::MyTypeDouble' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
1>c++-tests.cpp(50): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c++-tests.cpp(50): warning C4183: 'getDouble': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c++-tests.cpp(51): error C2039: 'MyTypeDouble' : is not a member of 'MyTypeTrait<0>'
1>          c++-tests.cpp(26) : see declaration of 'MyTypeTrait<0>'
1>c++-tests.cpp(51): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MyTypeDouble'
1>c++-tests.cpp(55): error C2535: 'void Implementation<0>::setDouble(void)' : member function already defined or declared
1>          c++-tests.cpp(51) : see declaration of 'Implementation<0>::setDouble'
1>c++-tests.cpp(50): error C3668: 'Implementation<0>::getDouble' : method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
1>c++-tests.cpp(51): error C3668: 'Implementation<0>::setDouble' : method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
1>c++-tests.cpp(42): error C2039: 'MyTypeInt' : is not a member of 'MyTypeTrait<1>'
1>          c++-tests.cpp(33) : see declaration of 'MyTypeTrait<1>'
1>          c++-tests.cpp(62) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Implementation<1>' being compiled
1>c++-tests.cpp(42): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getInt'
1>c++-tests.cpp(42): error C2433: 'Implementation<1>::MyTypeInt' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
1>c++-tests.cpp(42): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c++-tests.cpp(42): warning C4183: 'getInt': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c++-tests.cpp(43): error C2039: 'MyTypeInt' : is not a member of 'MyTypeTrait<1>'
1>          c++-tests.cpp(33) : see declaration of 'MyTypeTrait<1>'
1>c++-tests.cpp(43): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MyTypeInt'
1>c++-tests.cpp(47): error C2535: 'void Implementation<1>::setInt(void)' : member function already defined or declared
1>          c++-tests.cpp(43) : see declaration of 'Implementation<1>::setInt'
1>c++-tests.cpp(42): error C3668: 'Implementation<1>::getInt' : method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
1>c++-tests.cpp(43): error C3668: 'Implementation<1>::setInt' : method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
```

Comment: does this compiler support c++11?

Comment: Your compiler is too old to support the current C++ standard.

Comment: @RichardHodges MSVC2013 has alleged support for C++11. It's spotty, and SFINAE is one of the things it's worst at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't completely sure from the question whether you wanted to support either/or interface or a complete/NOP version of the 2 interfaces.

Here is one solution for the former.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct IntInterface
{
    virtual int getInt() const = 0;
    virtual void setInt(int value) = 0;
};

template<class TrueFalse>
struct IntInterfaceImpl {};

template<>
struct IntInterfaceImpl<std::true_type> : IntInterface
{
    int getInt() const override { return i_; }
    void setInt(int value) override { i_ = value; }

    int i_;
};

struct DoubleInterface
{
    virtual double getDouble() const = 0;
    virtual void setDouble(double value) = 0;
};

template<class TrueFalse>
struct DoubleInterfaceImpl {};

template<>
struct DoubleInterfaceImpl<std::true_type> : DoubleInterface
{
    double getDouble() const override { return i_; }
    void setDouble(double value) override { i_ = value; }

    double i_;
};


enum type {
    is_int,
    is_double
};

template<type T>
struct Implementation
: IntInterfaceImpl<std::integral_constant<bool, T == is_int>>
, DoubleInterfaceImpl<std::integral_constant<bool, T == is_double>>
{

};


int main()
{
    Implementation<type::is_int> i {};
    i.setInt(6);
    int a = i.getInt();

    Implementation<type::is_double> d {};
    d.setDouble(6.0);
    int b = d.getDouble();
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to your answer, so I'll accept it. I added an adapter between each interface and the class.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
// Actual interface implementation for the case of IntType
virtual typename MyTypeTrait<Type>::MyTypeInt getInt() const override { return 0; }
virtual void setInt(typename MyTypeTrait<Type>::MyTypeInt value) override {}

// Dummys for SFINAE - to be used in the case of DoubleType
int getInt(int) const { return 0; }
void setInt() {}
```

has no hope of working. SFINAE is only for substitution failures in the immediate context of template instantiation. These member functions are not in the immediate context of the class template instantiation, and so `MyTypeTrait<DoubleType>::MyTypeInt` is a *hard error*, not a substitution failure.

You'll have to rethink your design. Likely, you just have two completely separate interface implementations and then write something like:

```
template <int Type>
using Implementation = std::conditional_t<
    Type == IntType,
    IntImplementation,
    DoubleImplementation>;
```

or just explicit template specializations on all of these.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I understand correctly that it is considered a hard error because it happens when instantiating `Implementation<Type>`  and not when selecting an overload?

My real problem, BTW, is a little more complicated - both interfaces inherit from the same interface, and the differentiating calls need to be forwarded to another class (which is also determined by the template parameter), so your suggestion will not fit there.